# Create single objects form a table containing them

Tags: r, roracle

Here is my problem with R:

I have a table similar to this:

```
TABLE_NAME          COLUM_NAME          DATA_TYPE 
table_1               DATA              DATE
table_1               NAME              VARCHAR2
table_1               SURNAME           VARCHAR2
table_2               DATA              DATE
table_2               PACK              NUMBER
```

what i want to do is to create 2 different table from this based on the TABLE_NAME value that will have TABLE_NAME as name.
Like this

table_1

```
COLUM_NAME          DATA_TYPE 
   DATA              DATE
   NAME              VARCHAR2
   SURNAME           VARCHAR2
```

table_2

```
COLUM_NAME          DATA_TYPE
DATA              DATE
PACK              NUMBER
```

This way i can create a catalog of my tables, synonym and view of my db (with ROracle is not possible to fetch such metadata from the connection).

How can i Achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `split` to create a `list` of `data.frame`s

```
lst1 <- split(df1[-1], df1[[1]])
lst1
#$table_1
#  COLUM_NAME DATA_TYPE
#1       DATA      DATE
#2       NAME  VARCHAR2
#3    SURNAME  VARCHAR2

#$table_2
#  COLUM_NAME DATA_TYPE
#4       DATA      DATE
#5       PACK    NUMBER
```

Here, `split` is splitting the data.frame based on the factor provided (`f` in `split`).  It looks for rows that have the same elements in 'TABLE_NAME' and group them together and return a `list` of those similar rows

Comment: thanks this is exactly what i was searching. Can you explain a bit more how this works? Thanks

Comment: Thanks perfect, and it is possible to group with multiple variable ?

Comment: @RevivedPicard  Yes, you can just specify `df1[c("grp1", "grp2")]` as `f` and also to remove the unused combinations `drop = TRUE`

Answer (score 1):

from `tidyverse` you can `filter` and them remove the first column using `select`:

```
table1 <- df %>%
  filter(TABLE_NAME == "table_1") %>% 
  select(-TABLE_NAME)

table2 <- df %>%
  filter(TABLE_NAME == "table_2") %>% 
  select(-TABLE_NAME)
```

You could also place in a function to work through a load of data frames:

```
table_fun <- function(x) {
  df %>%
    filter(TABLE_NAME == x) %>%
    select(-TABLE_NAME)
}

table_2 <- table_fun("table_2")

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  COLUM_NAME DATA_TYPE
  <chr>      <chr>    
1 DATA       DATE     
2 PACK       NUMBER
```

Comment: Imagine there are more than 2 values in TABLE_NAME column.

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` you can also try:

```
df %>%
 group_split(TABLE_NAME)

[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  TABLE_NAME COLUM_NAME DATA_TYPE
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>    
1 table_1    DATA       DATE     
2 table_1    NAME       VARCHAR2 
3 table_1    SURNAME    VARCHAR2 

[[2]]
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  TABLE_NAME COLUM_NAME DATA_TYPE
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>    
1 table_2    DATA       DATE     
2 table_2    PACK       NUMBER
```

Comment: @zx8754 I think it could be helpful to keep it for people looking for this in the future.